# Проблема с перегрузкой

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Помогите, пожалуйста. Нужная переменная не перегружается.

**Class User: (наследуемый от Account)**

```
void User::resetAccount(){
   !Account();
}
```

**Class Account (Наследуемый от Money)**

```
    //Account.h
    class Account{
private:
    string fio;
    long id; //id
    int pin;
    Money m;
public:
    Account();
    Account(string FIO, long Ident, int Pin, Money M);
    Account operator!();

    //Account.cpp
    Account Account::operator!(){
    this->m.setSum(0);
    return *this;
    }
```

Метод setSum() в Money работает корректно. Спасибо.

Comment: А как мне тогда можно связать заменить локальный объект на вызываемый Account?

Comment: Как раз вы не создаете локальный объект, а создаете временный безымянный объект, который тут же уничтожается(сразу после выражения), и к нему не возможно применить оператор. А вот локальный объект  Account a;   и можете выполнить   !a; Ну и причем тут перегрузка?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, вы хотите

```
void User::resetAccount(){ !*this; }
```

Ну, или

```
void User::resetAccount(){ this->operator!(); }
```

Если `User` и в самом деле корректно наследует `Account`.